# Symfony 1.4 sfmailer picking wrong host

Tags: email, symfony-1.4, swiftmailer

I'm using symfony 1.4 with propel 1.4

I've following setting in factories.yml

```
dev:
  mailer:
    class: sfMailer
    param:
      logging:           %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
      charset:           %SF_CHARSET%
      delivery_strategy: realtime
      transport:
        class: Swift_SmtpTransport
        params:
          host:     mail.myserver.com
          port:     26
          username: webmaster@myserver.com
          password: mypass
```

Running following code:

```
$mailer=$this->getMailer()->composeAndSend($from, $to, $subject, $message);
```

issues following error

```
Connection could not be established with host localhost [A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. #10060]
```

My problem is, it is trying to connect to localhost, even when I'd given different host in factories.yml. Can anyone please tell me where is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo mistake in factories.

Try changing `params` to `param` under `transport`, if it is present in your real factories.yml.